# MySQL doesn't use index if the condition value is not wrapped in quote marks

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are the queries:

```
# explain select * from t1 where user_ip=123 limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ALL  | user_ip       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  262 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

# explain select * from t1 where user_ip='123' limit 1;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref  | user_ip       | user_ip | 47      | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The `user_ip` field is varchar type. My question is: why does the index(key) is not used in the first query, but is used in the second one. The only difference is the quote marks.

Comment: Can you also post the results of `DESC t1;`

Comment: Don't compare apples (numbers) to oranges (strings). Always use the literal format that matches the column you compare it against. Never, ever rely on implicit type conversion.

Answer (score 4):

From the MySQL Documentation [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html):

> For comparisons of a string column with a number, MySQL cannot use an index on the column to look up the value quickly. ... The reason for this is that there are many different strings that may convert to the value 1, such as '1', ' 1', or '1a'.

That page has a bullet list of all the different types of comparisons. Finally, it ends with:

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

Since none of the previous cases include comparing strings with numbers, this default case applies. This is why the string is converted to a number, not the other way around as you expect.

Comment: As your table is varchar it works when using a quotes, because it is treated as a string then. If you need it to work for your first query you need to change the structure to INT.

Comment: The reason in the doc is not reasonable. it should convert the number(in query command) to string and use index, not convert the string(in database) to number and test with the number we provided in the query command.

Comment: Read some more of the documentation. It says that when you compare strings and numbers, it converts the string to a number.

Comment: e.g. `"abc" = 0` is true.